# SQL Server Log Shipping configuration screen

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to configure log shipping in SQL server but I cannot see the bottom page of Transaction Log Backup Settings.

anyone know why?

I use this version of SQL Server:

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change to an upper screen resolution to view all configuration page of Log Shipping (and another pages, like e.g. Backup/Restore Tasks Config).

Check this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/77cc8755-16d7-4a45-8b68-d07314a889dd/hyper-v-full-screen) for this topic at Technet Forum.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can I do it?

Comment: I checked, this is not the screen. the bottom page just not there